# Conversion specifier %ju

Tags: c, printf, scanf

In the following page, I found the code like

[CERT INT15-C Use intmax_t or uintmax_t for formatted IO on programmer-defined integer types](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT15-C.+Use+intmax_t+or+uintmax_t+for+formatted+IO+on+programmer-defined+integer+types)

```
uintmax_t temp;

if(scanf("%ju", &temp) != 1) {
   ...
```

I am not familiar with the "%ju" specifier. And I am not successful in finding the explanation of the "%ju" on the Internet.

Is this defined by some specific compiler environment, or generally used one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`%ju` is just the `%u` (unsigned) format with a `j` length modifier, the latter being defined in the C99 standard as:

> `j` — Speciﬁes that a following `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, `X`, or `n` conversion specifier applies to an argument with type pointer to `intmax_t` or `uintmax_t`.